# Persistent Logins

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am following this article on creating persistent login cookies with my ASP.NET site:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.encrypt.aspx

The issue is that when I navigate to the page, I get the following compiler error:

`Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'ASP.administration_login_aspx' does not contain a definition for 'Login_Click' and no extension method 'Login_Click' accepting a first argument of type 'ASP.administration_login_aspx' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Can anyone tell me why this is.  The error message doesn't really say much and I don't believe I am missing a directive or assembly reference.  The code builds without any problems.

EDIT: I did not include code because I said I was following that link which includes code.  I copy/pasted from the example.

Comment: Make sure the method is public or protected, and the signature is correct..

Comment: Check my edit about code.

Comment: @MikeChristensen That was the problem.  The example said private, but as soon as I changed it to protected, it worked.  Thanks.

Comment: @Trido - Ah, the example is actually correct since it's within a `<script>` tag in the same file.  It all gets bundled up into the same class.  I've added an answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.encrypt.aspx) is *actually* correct, since the code is inline (within a `<script runat="server">` block).  The ASP.NET compiler creates a temporary class with the included code, and compiles it into a DLL in a temp directory.  Since the event handlers are being bound within the same generated class, it can be private.

However, if you're using a code behind, the ASP.NET compiler will actually generate a temporary class that *derives* from the one in your code behind.  For this reason, the event handler needs to be public or protected so it can be accessed by the subclass.

Comment: I did not realise the distinction, thanks for educating me!  I did add the C# to a code behind.